# Blazor / WPF differences in resolving the same image URL

Tags: wpf, blazor

I have WPF and Blazor code displaying the same image from the same locally hosted URL.
WPF works in all cases, but Blazor only works with localhost or 127.0.0.1.

In WPF, **all of these work** and hit the controller:

```
<Image Source="http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/MyApi/MyEndpoint/GetImage"/>
<Image Source="http://localhost:5000/api/v1/MyApi/MyEndpoint/GetImage"/>
<Image Source="http://192.168.1.34:5000/api/v1/MyApi/MyEndpoint/GetImage"/>
<Image Source="http://MYMACHINENAME:5000/api/v1/MyApi/MyEndpoint/GetImage"/>
```

However, in Blazor **only these two work** (the others do not even hit the controller):

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/MyApi/MyEndpoint/GetImage" type="image/jpeg"/>
<img src="http://localhost:5000/api/v1/MyApi/MyEndpoint/GetImage" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO #1**

The Console displays this te
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Digging in, it seems that Blazor is swapping the `http` scehme/protocal for `https`, I have no idea why.

**ADDITIONAL INFO #2**

[image]

[image]

Am I missing a startup setting in Blazor (server-side) here that might cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible reasons WPF would happily retrieve data from an endpoint but a browser won't. The two most common ones would be -

1. CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) settings. This is a server-side option that is enforced by the browser. In an ASP.NET Core server, you would find this being configured via calls to [UseCors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (an extension method for `IApplicationBuilder`). This would be ignored by WPF (and any other non-browser desktop application that made raw API calls) but would be enforced by the browser, even when using Blazor. It's quite possible your server is configuring CORS to allow `127.0.0.1:5000` and `localhost:5000` (since they would be pretty universal for all developers) but not the others.
2. The [Content-Security-Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/content-security-policy?view=aspnetcore-7.0) header can also be configured to allow resrouce fetching only from certain URLs. This is another server-side setting that the browser enforces but WPF and desktop apps wouldn't.

Based on your comment, I'd also add these:

3. The CSP might also require `upgrade-insecure-requests` which would cause the browser to prefer HTTPS. However, this doesn't explain why some URLs work but not others.
4. If your server responses include the [Strict-Transport-Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) header, this could explain the HTTP->HTTPS switcheroo and why it occurs on some URLs and not others. This header is a bit tricky; as the spec explains it causes the browser to upgrade requests to HTTPS if the browser ever previosuly connected via HTTPS. So if you previously had other projects at `192.168.1.34:5000` or `MYMACHINENAME:5000` that used HTTPS, even though this one doesn't, it would remember that it previously accessed these URLs through HTTPS and try to do the same for your Blazor app. In fact I believe that the browser will behave this way even if the current site doesn't require `Strict-Transport-Securtiy`, i.e., the HTTPS preference is remembered by the browser and sticks indefinitely. The way to get around this is by clearing your browser history so it forgets that it previously connected via HTTPS. You could also try a different browser; incognito mode might also forget the HTTPS history and behave properly.

If any of these is in play it will be evident from the Network and/or Console tabs of the browser debugger at the time the calls are attempted. In any of these cases the browser would either block the call or it would fail so you wouldn't see it hit the controller method. And note again that WPF would be immune to any of these possible issues.

If none of these help then I'd ask you to show us all the resposne headers for a simple GET to either of the endpoints that works properly, either from Postman or even just using the browser address bar. Very likely something will stand out that can explain the redirect.

Comment: This was already in place (CORS) - but as you suggested looking at the console tabs of the browser did reveal something else - Blazor seems to be changing the `http` of my URL to `https` and then failing since there is no https protocol in play.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Aha. That brings up more possibilities. I'll update my answer. :) If that still doesn't solve it, I'd ask you to post all the return headers from a GET directly to those URLs that are not getting retrieved, either from Postman or even just using the browser address bar. Virtually certain there is something in those response headers causing the browser to do this. Blazor would not just alter URLs on its own.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt thanks for accepting. Curious what it wound up being (assuming you identified it)?

Comment: Actually - my apologies @just-answer-the-question, this hasn't fixed it as I thought.  I had run a test with an HTTPS endpoint running and of course it worked, I haven't yet cracked stopping the http:\\ request being changed by chrome (?) to https:\\ ...

Comment: Ah ok. Well if you can please post all the headers returned by the server from a simple GET to the successful endpoints I'm fairly confident the answer will reveal itself there.

Comment: Also did you try an http:// request in incognito mode as I suggested? Remember strict-transport-security might not reveal itself in the current server headers but would be remembered by the browser based on past requests to those urls.

Comment: Request headers contains Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 .. will post in question.  It seems http requests from an https site in chrome might not be possible by browser design?

Comment: Incognito tab also fails btw ... exactly the same behaviour - failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Ok that's interesting that your *request* header has `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests`. So something is inserting that into your requests client-side. Have you seen this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/content-security-policy?view=aspnetcore-7.0. Scroll to the section on "Blazor WebAssembly" and note the `meta` tag. Do you have anything like that in your `index.html`?

Comment: No, I see nothing of that sort on the blazor page (it's blazor server side tho) - in the rendered version (in chrome) or in the project itself ...

Comment: Gosh that's frustrating. Sorry I'm out of ideas. Hopefully the exercise will help someone else at least. If you figure out what it is I hope you follow up, I'm pretty curious myself (and like you I also have WPF and Blazor apps hitting the same endpoints so it's uniquely in my sphere of interest).